# udev rule not working for action "add"

Tags: linux, udev

I have the following udev rule (`/etc/udev/rules.d/97-automounter.rules`), which works for the action "remove" but does not work for the action "add".  The script for the action "add" does work if run manually.

```
# rule: mount/umount /dev/vd* when EBS volume is attached.
ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/vd[b-z]", ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/udev-automounter.sh %k"
ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/vd[b-z]", ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/udev-autounmounter.sh %k"
```

Not sure how to correct this or debug.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the same call whether it is added or removed:

```
"/usr/local/sbin/udev-autounmounter.sh %k"
```

which I am not sure what %k is calling but that is prolly the dev location.  Well you would then need the script to know whether it needs to run the add block or remove block of code.  If needed break the add portion out and create udev-add.sh and copy the remove portion to a script udev-rem.sh and adjust the command you have there so it calls the udev-add.sh for the add portion and the udev-rem.sh for the removal.

That should get you going.  Otherwise you would need a way to tell the script to call the add subroutine for adds and the different and separate sub routine for removal.  You could use a variable if you MUST use the same script so that when you remove it also changes a variable to something so when the script runs it checks the variable and says hey if this variable says remove I run this portion and if there is no variable set OR if it is set to something else I run just the add part.

The way that command looks right now it prolly is running the same device add subroutine when called for both adding and removing the device.